# uu cookie: why Cookie differs ftom Set-Cookie?

Tags: cookies

In Chrome let's open a new **incognito** window.
And open Developer tools.

Just to be on the safe side:

```
document.cookie
```

Empty.

Let's type an address: http://www [point] imdb [point] com/
The address is quite arbitrary: taken out of the sky for learning purposes.

At the Network tab find www  [point] imdb  [point] com
Let's have a look at how request looks: no cookies. It's ok.

And now let's pay attention to the response headers, namely at Set-Cookie.
Let's copy them all to a text file.

Now let's reload the page.
Find www  [point] imdb  [point] com again in the name column.

Now in the request we can see Cookie. It is predictable.

But what troubles me is the cookie uu. Well, it really differs from what the server has set.

Example:

We have saved in the text file:

```
uu=BCYr_ZHeJZBVTCoesiUG1rfgB8gy2UE_2TW_RmGhVKAtUkbp0DQqkB3fEfwB-h_SyB2wWoFK6Fk6%0D%0AE28Vu2a9OBoOkRXwBMwWZ5KBFJSEpgGW1X8U0OzP4h9iEeopN3H8hQHhdOwTZg6c8_5g0rGJ6j53%0D%0AXi6Hcnachaipi66oTTGzZ78_jUJybf39LmpcXXZA_iaPxD5HOkPKk9jGOEyZCyfDBjG16Ii9PhNr%0D%0ANdUB6d84e0PeapF_NhjvU7tSH9c6qBpt-gAYaeJpG5Zz8-giS2sc9A%0D%0A
```

And in the request we have now:

```
uu=BCYg0XCJTAbG2yFp8o3oWf93wy3bV0G7JFDH0g79bS9xYTJzYjqyEKKy5Yu_dOkjZg8jokTxlB6cOK42Y-JjFAJ4mucLGmdcXRJrYvluJouBHCcIbCdTYESBYdzxv6_WMcH2crK-JY8EzjVAKBipvpjDFjw_6zi6oCK78_hrjauyR2JvHqWHCMEeyWNCbUQI--DKaQo4CjBM975FCuUYZV97NV9rt_VFOpbUykUtJDajrFE5lULdosdyNjwR8nVhNcFgNLa9HRZc-e2jVE3F1-xipZg0uJCrn5ndut5BrI66oMo;
```

Well, could you comment on how can it be?

Comment: Well, maybe something stored a new value into the cookie with that name …? Like a client-side script for example.

Comment: I have thought about that. But why? As far as I can understand, this may be a unique user flag. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_user Why should they change it?

Comment: It makes rather little sense to question why arbitrary websites might do certain stuff ... As for the technical side, it does not necessarily have to be a client-side script; one of the embedded resources that come from the same domain might also just have overwritten that cookie.

Comment: Well, this may mean that this site is not suitable for scrutinizing for learning purposes.